# Java Using Scanner to Read File and Then Read Line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a scanner that reads a file and deletes the spaces between each word. I can get this much but I can't get it to where they stay on the same line. I can't get the program to read a line, delete the spaces, and then go to the next line. This is the text from my practice project:

```
four      score   and

seven               years ago         our

fathers brought             forth
    on this          continent
a         new

nation
```

I'm currently only getting the first line

and this is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CollapseSpace {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File ("textwithspaces.txt"));
        String nextLine = fileInput.nextLine();
        Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(nextLine);
        while(fileInput.hasNext()){
            nextLine = fileInput.nextLine();
            while(lineInput.hasNext()){
                System.out.print(lineInput.next() + " "); // I tried to add a fileInput.NextLine() to consume the line but it isn't working properly            
            }
            System.out.println();
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: I know the line "nextLine = fileInput.nextLine();" isn't being used, but i'm not sure how to go about making it take the loop to the next line down in the text... it runs on the first line and then nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to iterate line by line and remove spaces between words then you only need one loop, sample code below should do the trick

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    final Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File ("src/main/resources/textwithspaces.txt"));
    while(fileInput.hasNext()){
        final String nextLine = fileInput.nextLine();
        // remove all spaces
        final String lineWithOutSpaces = nextLine.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        System.out.println(lineWithOutSpaces);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `*` to import classes. It is generally thought of as "bad practice" since it can interfere with your own classes, also it is not very explicit.

You need to loop the nextLine method inside your own loop. And also using a replaceAll method of the string would be good.

I have shown an example below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Create an object to represent a text file
        File file = new File("textwithspaces.txt");

        // Create a scanner with the text file as argument
        Scanner scannerWithFile = new Scanner(file);

        // Continue as long as it has a next line
        do {
            // Replace strings
            String thisLine = scannerWithFile.nextLine();

            // Only print the line out if not empty
            if (!thisLine.isEmpty()) {
                // Replace all spaces
                thisLine = thisLine.replaceAll(" ", "");

                // Print
                System.out.println(thisLine);
            }
        } while (scannerWithFile.hasNext());
    }
}
```

I also switched your while loop to a do while loop, this is so you can just instantly go into the loop without having to check for a condition first, it is done before next iteration.

Answer (score -1):

Your biggest problem is that you declared `nextLine = fileInput.nextLine();` outside of the loop, and then used that in `Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(nextLine);` so it becomes the first line of the text, but then never changes.

I also agree with the other comment that says you shouldn't be using `*`, it's considered bad practice to import broadly like that, as you're importing a whole lot of stuff you won't be using.

I reconstructed your code to make it work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File ("textwithspaces.txt"));

        while(fileInput.hasNext()){
            String nextLine = fileInput.nextLine();
            Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(nextLine);

            while(lineInput.hasNext()){
                System.out.print(lineInput.next() + " ");            
            }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```